# What is the point of version ranges in csproj if it's always going to force the lowest version?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

So I having some trouble wrapping my head around how nuget package versioning is supposed to work. As I understand it Version="6.*" (or `[6.0,7.0)`) means that any `6.x.x` version is valid and that the default behavior is supposed to be that it's going use the lowest compatible version in that range. Correct? What I had assumed, was that it meant if it didn't already have a version in that range to use, then it would fetch the lowest version, but instead, what it seems to be doing is removing what is installed and replacing it with the lowest possible version and this is causing problems.

Example:
Project A has package `foo-2.4` installed. It also has package `bar-1.0` installed that has a dependency on `foo-2.*`. Logically, I would assume that installing package `bar` should be fine because it'll see `foo-2.4` and use it since it's in the correct range, but instead what is happening is that it's trying to remove `foo-2.4` and replace it with `foo-2.0` and that fails because the package manager detects a downgrade and aborts the installation.

Am I misunderstanding/missing something here or is the NuGet package manager not  handling this correctly? Is there some quirk with the nuspec now being in the csproj file or maybe I'm supposed to add something in to make sure it dependency is properly specified?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you describe. I created a netcoreapp2.1 console app, added `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` v9.4.2, which depends on `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common` v9.4.2, which in turn depends on `Newtonsoft.Json` 10.0.2. I then added `Newtsonsoft.Json` 11.* to my project, and it uses 11.0.2. Do you have a sample that reproduces the issue?

Comment: The issue is with internal packages in production code so I'll have to build a couple dummies to reproduce. I'll come back with it when I get a chance.